# Installing an R package from local unzipped folder

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran, install.packages

I am having difficulty installing an unzipped package on a Windows 7 computer without administrative privileges and no internet access. I am using the RGui (not RStudio).

Right now I have an unzipped library sitting in a directory. Unfortunately, when I try:

```
install.packages("C://path//to//directory", 
    repos = NULL, 
    lib = "C://path//to//newDirectory")
```

I am getting the error:

```
Warning in `install.packages("C://path//to//directory",`   :
   'lib = "C://path//to//newDirectory"' is not writable
```

Which is strange because I do have write privileges to where I am attempting to store the package.

When I get this error, I also get a popup from RGui:

```
Would you like to use a personal library instead?
```

If I click `Yes`, it throws the error:

```
Error in `install.packages("C://path//to//directory",`   :
    type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'
```

I also cannot install **devtools**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is an unzipped Windows binary (e.g., from CRAN), you can just copy and paste the entire package directory into your library folder. You could also, presumably, use `file.copy()` to do so if you wanted to do it within R. `install.packages()` is failing (weirdly) because you're giving it something other than the typical package source or zipped binary that it is expecting.

Answer (score 51):

The solution to installing a package that's been unzipped into a folder is as follows:

```
install.packages("C:/path to folder with the package", 
repos = NULL, 
type = "source")
```

Comment: `type = "source"` is the default on Linux but not on Windows platforms. 
System information used by `install.packages()` to determine default
installation parameters `getOption("repos")` and `getOption("pkgType")`.

Answer (score 7):

I think the error message is actually just wrong.  You need to give the file name of the package, not just the directory.

```
install.packages("C://path//to//directory//MY_PACKAGE.tar.gz", 
    repos = NULL, 
    lib = "C://path//to//newDirectory")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The issue is I no longer have the compressed package, I'm wondering if I can do it on a folder instead of a tar.gz?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do that.  But you can rebuild your package from the command line using: R CMD build MY_PACKAGE

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this using devtools:

```
devtools::install("path/to/package/folder")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have zip file, you can install as follows

```
install.packages("E:\\R-Packages\\plyr_1.8.4.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to R-studio
2. Click the install icon in the packages section found in the right side of the window
3. A new window pops up
4. Set "Install from: Package Archive file" "Package Archive: Browse the unzipped file and select it"
5. Click install
   This installs the package to the R library

Answer (score 1):

If it is a package that has been removed from the repo but you have an installed version (and want to e.g. move it), you can do this in RStudio on Windows:

1. zip the folder in which the package currently is (using any of the usual programs, 7zip, etc.)
2. move it to a folder accessible from the R version you want to install to
3. in RStudio click on Tools->Install packages and choose "Package Archive File (zip; tar.gz)" in the "Install from" dropdown.

I have just managed to move an obsolete package using this method and it can be loaded as expected.